# How to import videos from YouTube to Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to allow authorization for a YouTube video to be transferred to Google Cloud Platform so I can run Google Cloud Video Intelligence on it? I looked through YouTube's APIs and there doesn't seem to be any download or transfer API options.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading YouTube videos is a breach of YouTube's Terms of Service ([link](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms)).

You must contact YouTube to discuss usage outside of the Terms of Service.

The relevant Terms of Service section:

> The following restrictions apply to your use of the Service. You are
> not allowed to:
>
> access, reproduce, download, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display,
> sell, license, alter, modify or otherwise use any part of the Service
> or any Content except: (a) as expressly authorized by the Service; or
> (b) with prior written permission from YouTube and, if applicable, the
> respective rights holders;

This answer on Stack Exchange Law discusses this in more detail:

https://law.stackexchange.com/a/1650/24007